# What is the DDL syntax for the creation of a table with a blob field in ODBC?

Tags: sql, odbc

I am supposing that there is an ODBC SQL syntax that allows me to create a table in ODBC and that one of its fields is a long binary field, so I can store an image.
I want this to work with Access, MySQL and SQLite.
Can someone give me a sample sql create table ... statement that does the job?

Answer (score -1):

To create a table use this query `CREATE TABLE table_name (image BLOB)`
and then you could insert it with let's say Python3 (because it's the most convenient) like this:

```py
import sqlite3
import sys


def get_binary_data(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()


def insert_into_blob(imagepath):
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "INSERT INTO 'table_name' ('image') VALUES (?)"
        data = get_binary_data(imagepath)
        cursor.execute(query, (data,))
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("error: could not insert into blob", error, file=sys.stderr)
    finally:
        if (connection):
            connection.close()

insert_into_blob('/path/to/image.png')
```

Comment: That's not ODBC you are using. It's the SQLite3 interface